# How do I extract a substring from a random position in a string using built-in functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a series of data stored in the following fashion:

```
Word of various kinds (ANT\username1) and even more words
This is another row, the words are random (ANT\username2)
Thankfully the username only ever shows once (ANT\username1)
```

Above represents three seperate rows.

The general flow of this data is:

- Parenthesis can appear anywhere in the text
- The username portion of each string (ANT\usernamex) will only ever appear once
- The text preceeding and proceeding the username portion is always different lengths.
- The username text may not always be present

As you probably already guessed what I need to do is take the username from each row and where it isn't present return null. Unfortunately I have no idea how to approach this - I've played around with left() and right() functions but don't really know how else to tackle this. Would appreciate if any answers that use a number of functions to accomplish the task have a quick blurb explaining the flow of logic (so I can then read the documentation for the functions to learn).

Comment: try PATINDEX : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395(v=sql.105).aspx. But note string handling is not TSQL's strong point (it wasn't designed for manipulating strings); might want to do this in a SQL CLR function.

Comment: @MitchWheat I thought about that but thought I'd see if it could be done using functions first (it's a one-off data fix process so doesn't have to be quick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the specific results when the data is not as expected. This works for exactly the format `'(ANT\....)'`.

```
-- sample table
create table t(s varchar(max));
insert t select 
'Word of various kinds (ANT\) blank' union all select
'Word of various kinds (ANT) blank' union all select
'Word of various kinds (ANT\ no closing' union all select
'Word of various kinds (ANT\(ANT\me) double up' union all select
'' union all select
'(ANT\' union all select
null union all select
'Word of various kinds (ANT\username1) and even more words' union all select
'This is another row, the words are random (ANT\username2)' union all select
'Thankfully the username only ever shows once (ANT\username1)';

-- Query
select Original = s,
       Extracted = nullif(STUFF(LEFT(s, CharIndex(')',s+')',
                   PatIndex('%(ANT\%', s)) -1), 1,
                   PatIndex('%(ANT\%', s + '(ANT\')+4,''),'')
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks - very much appreciated.. Now to try to figure out what this is doing :)